# Can this double breaker be moved?

Tags: circuit-breaker

This double 60 breaker WAS in the space above where it is pictures now. Power is cut and I moved it down. Is there a reason why I couldn’t do this? The reason I want to move it was because it would not seat properly—kept popping out but does fine here. This box is a house cut-off and feeds my workshop. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Breakers do not care where they are placed in a panel(high amperage usually placed near the top).  With it popping off/not seating in one place, might mean some damage/defect of the panel or breaker, and should be checked out by an electrician.  It does seem like the proper breaker for that panel.

Comment: ok, appreciate the answer. It is odd the it fits perfectly and is snug in this spot and not the one above it. Maybe the metal piece that the breaker latches onto above is bent slightly or something (but does not appear to be).

Comment: There seems to be a definite misalignment at the top and bottom edges of the 60A breaker vs the breakers on the right. The 60A breaker seems to be sitting too high. (The stack of breakers on the right don't appear to be sagging from the main breaker.)

Comment: That is why I said have it checked by an electrician that can see everything there.  Breakers should fit the same way at the top or bottom, or right or left side.  If they don't fit right, something is wrong.

Comment: The problem is, if the stab is burnt, the breaker is burnt too.  If you move it to another stab, the arcing will continue and you'll have another burnt stab.  I would pop off the top 4 rows of breakers and shoot well lit pix of the stabs, so you have normal and ??? to compare.  The breakers can dangle by their wires, and you can turn the power back on during that to take a picture.  Do you have a generator? Do you want one?

Comment: @crip659 Obviously you’ve never heard of CTL. Probably not a factor here, but it was a thing.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem moving the breaker to another slot. I'd be more concerned about why it's not seating correctly in the first place. The exposed bus tab seems to be bent downward a bit and that whole right row is down a fraction. I'd pull out the 30 amp double pole breaker and check it out.

The only other issue is that you knocked out two spaces for the relocated breaker in the cover. Now you need a filler plug for the top two spaces.